# How safe is it to use OkHttp

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

How safe is it to use OkHttp3 for your REST API?

For example, if my website has some login/signup process, and my app sends requests with OkHttp3 client. How much can I trust that someone can't take his phone, plug it into Android Studio and look into the logs and find the links for all the requests I'm calling?

There's also the matter of decompiling the app, and easily accessing the base Uri I'm using in my app.

I'm not sure how OkHttp works, so can someone tell me about the security used in the client and how much I can trust it?

Answer (score 0):

If a link is on the internet, then it's public.  There is no point trying to hide that fact.
You need to focus on the securing the endpoint(s) the app is talking to for confidentiality, integrity and availability

You need to read up on Web security.  Take a look at the OWASP Top 10 and related guides.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you worried about your URL address? Whenever you expose an API on the internet anyone can find your API URL address. There are easier ways than reading logs of your app.

What is your exact worry? What do you need to keep secure? What is important for you?